# Passing value from one jsp to another

Tags: java, jsp

First jsp page contains code:

```
<a href='select.jsp?param1=${person.name}'>link to other jsp</a>
```

In html this link refers to:

```
http://sitename/select.jsp?param1=gsdf
```

A code from `select.jsp` page:

```
<c:out value="${param1}">No name</c:out>
<br/><%=request.getParameter("param1")%>
```

But I get:

> No name
>
> gsdf

Why the value of `param1` did not pass to second jsp in the case of using `c:out`?

Comment: c:out gets value from the actual java object that is being passed, not the value of http request parameter. In this example I think it's something like <c:out value="${person.name}">, if there is a field on your page that is bound to Person.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use EL (JSP Expression Language).

from javaDoc :

> param: Maps a request parameter name to a single value

so you juste need to do something like

```
<c:out value="${param.param1}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send Using Session object.

```
session.setAttribute("prsonName", prsonName);
```

These values will now be available from any jsp as long as your session is still active.

```
Object userid = session.getAttribute("prsonName");
```